# Sobrecarga de subscribe deprecada en Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode, angular8

Al consumir un servicio post de un api, hemos utilizamos el método:

```
.subscribe( data => {}, error =>{});
```

Recientemente me he dado cuenta que visual studio code muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> @deprecated — Use an observer instead of a complete callback

He intentado mandar un objeto con 3 funciones (según la documentación oficial de angular:

```
.subscribe({ next: data=>{

    }, error: err=>{

    }, complete: () =>{

    } });
```

pero aún obtengo el mensaje de sobrecarga deprecada. ¿Me podrían orientar acerca de cuál es la forma correcta de hacer esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que tal Gustavo, bienvenido a S.O. en español... importaste el modulo de rxjs?? tal como esta tu código es la forma "correcta" de usarlo...  aun si te sale ese mensaje no deberías tener ningun problema, está en desuso, pero no fue eliminado aun ...

Answer (score 0):

```
.subscribe({
    complete: () => { ... }, // completeHandler
    error: () => { ... },    // errorHandler 
    next: () => { ... },     // nextHandler
    someOtherProperty: 42
});
```